# Copying to std::chrono::milliseconds with memcpy() gives error -Werror=class-memaccess

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, memcpy, c++-chrono

For this code:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 6> myArray = {123, 123, 112, 0, 15};
std::chrono::milliseconds dest{0};
memcpy(&dest, &myArray, 5);
```

Gcc gives the following error:

```
warning: 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' copying an object of type 'std::chrono::milliseconds'
{aka 'struct std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >'}
with 'private' member 'std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >::__r'
from an array of 'struct std::array<unsigned char, 6>';
use assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
```

What would be the best way to handle this when I need to copy only 5 bytes from array and not the whole array?

Here is my full code:

```
std::array<uint8_t, 6> myArray = {0};
uint32_t time = 500000000;

memcpy(&myArray, &time, 4);
std::chrono::milliseconds ret{0};

memcpy(&ret, &myArray, 4);
```

So im trying to get same value in `ret` as the one in `time`

Comment: Two problems: First of all you copy the `std::array` object, not the data it contains (you're lucky that `std::array` happen to be an aggregate that contains the data itself); Secondly how do you know that `std::chrono::milliseconds` is five bytes and in which order the data is stored internally inside the `dest` object?

Comment: And why are you doing this memory copying? What is the actual problem that's supposed to solve?

Comment: where does `myArray` come from? What is the meaning of its elements? The things is that you dont even get a guarantee for what the actual type of the counter inside `std::chrono::milliseconds` really is. The only thing you know for certain is that it is some signed integer type of at least 45 bits

Comment: I have octet string that is always stored in fixed size of 6 octets e.g, but data that is valid to me is stored in first 5 octets, which i want to represent as chrono::milliseconds

Comment: @Slava I guess i should make it clear in question that im not interested in answers from "trying to be funny, dunno what to do with my time" type of people

Comment: What does the data represent? `i want to represent as chrono::milliseconds` makes no sense, either it is `chrono::milliseconds` object or is not. How were the data created?

Comment: @KamilCuk the data obviously represents time, so its easier to handle it further in code as chrono object, but is that really important?

Comment: `represents time` How does it "represent time"? Does it store the number of seconds since birth of Jesus? There are many ways to "represent time". If it's a number, what endianess is used to encode it? Yes, that is really important. The bytes that compose the object `chrono::milliseconds` do not "represent time" - they "represent" `chrono::millisecond` object. Or maybe the first byte is the year since birth of Jesus, the second byte is the month, the third is the day of the month... etc?

Comment: @Bodega I rather refrain from assume motivation of others, but I think the message slavas comment was pure serious. Your quesiton is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where the way you chose to solve it is not viable but the actual problem you are trying to solve is not clear from the question

Comment: so what you should have made clear in the question is: what really is "this" in "What would be the best way to handle this"

Comment: "I guess i should make it clear in question that im not interested in answers from" I am fine with that. But maybe you should better spent you time making your question clear and explain what you are trying to achieve instead of "I am trying to copy random amount of bytes and I get this warning, how do I solve it?"

Comment: Okay, the five first bytes represents some time-stamp. But *how* does it represent this time? A time-stamp from what kind of epoch? How are you supposed to combine these bytes to get the time-stamp? And where do you get them from? Have you read the documentation about the system that "gives" or "sends" these bytes to you? What does the documentation say?

Comment: Copying C++ objects with `memcpy` is in *most cases* a bug.

Comment: @Slava Use your words to ask more about the problem, then. No need for banter. Ask for clarification - you're in the wrong here.

Comment: But we don't know what the bytes *mean*! That's the problem for us. And possibly for you too. And if we don't know what the bytes mean or how they should be interpreted, we can't tell you how to convert them to a `std::chrono::milliseconds` object. What we *can* tell you is that it's not going to be done the way you show in the question.

Comment: @alteredinstance OP should be motivated to get answer, not me providing it. So you are saying I am wrong not to begging for clarification so I can get honor to answer this question?

Comment: now you are trying to be funny (didnt work for me btw). `{123, 123, 112, 0, 15};` is not a time in any well accepted format. Those are raw bytes and there must be some interpretation to give them meaning. For one you can have different endianess

Comment: @Slava I agree he's not doing much to help himself, especially with his last comment... Lol. In the future it's best to just be polite and ask for clarification.

Comment: @alteredinstance I usually do, but sometimes it is obvious that OP does not bother to explain him/her/itself. So I tried to show him/her/it my frustration in a clear way.

Comment: I have data (representing time in millisecs) stored in uint32 variable (out of memory limitation lets say), this value is then stored in size 6 octet string (always, fixed size for that data) before sending over some external interface, and when i receive that octet string i need to get same value i had stored in variable from the start, but only this time i would like to have it stored as chrono::milliseconds because that would make it easier to use for me, rather then have it as uint32 as before... so when i receive that data i convert it from octet string to array of that size (myArray)

Comment: if you already have a `uint32` you dont need `memcpy` anymore. Having the contents of your last comment in the question would have avoided some complications ;)

Comment: What endianess is used to store the number? What is a "string" in `6 octet string`? For me, I would assume "octet" mean byte, and "octet string" means sequence of bytes, is this correct? Why would you use 6 bytes to encode `uint32_t` variable? With bytes having 8 bits, 4 bytes are enough for `uint32_t`? Does your bytes have less then 8 bits? Or, maybe like, does the "6 octet string" really represent a representation of the number in base 10 encoded using 6 ASCII digit characters?

Comment: `So im trying to get same value in ret as the one in time` `std::chrono::milliseconds ret{time};`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Cmon man, i appreciate you trying to help, but just assume that it absolutely has to be size of 6 (or whatever, point is that i need only some of those bytes, first 5 e.g.). Yes, you assumed right for octet string. On the other side that value is handled in uint32_t but why does not concern me, my fault though. if its handled as uint32_t i care for only 4 octets out of that octet string/array, i mislead you there maybe. But the point is still kinda same, i just want certain bytes from that array stored as chrono::millisecondss

Comment: So first 1. Reconstruct the `uint32_t` number from you array. Then 2. Call the constructor of `std;:chrono::milliseconds` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safer way to implement this that doesn't rely on knowing the internal layout of `std::chrono::duration` would be to copy to an integer then pass the integer to the duration:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 6> myArray = {123, 123, 112, 0, 15};
int64_t milliseconds = 0;
memcpy(&milliseconds, &myArray, 5);
std::chrono::milliseconds dest{milliseconds};
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, if i know that myArray value will still fit into 32bit value, can i store it in uin32_t, and then to ::milliseconds?

Comment: no, not if you want to `memcpy` 5 bytes, if you only `memcpy` 4 bytes then yes you can use a 32-bit integer

Comment: Ahh, makes sense, thx

Answer (score 3):

You initialise the duration like this:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds::rep r = 0;
// initialise r with your array
std::chrono::milliseconds dest{r};
```

Now, you need to figure out how to initialise `r`. You could use `memcpy`, but then there will be a dependency between the format of the array and the representation of integers on the target system. In other words, the data that the program reads will not be compatible across incompatible systems.

The portable way to implement integer de-serialisation is to specify the format of the data - usual choice is big endian octets. Once you've determined the format of the input, you can use bit shifts, bit masks and bitwise-or operations to combine the individual octets into an integer value. While this is mostly straightforward, it has a few easy mistakes to make (especially with signed integers), so I recommend using a pre-existing solution. The standard library does not come with de-serialisation functionality.

---

Regarding your edit:

> ```
> uint32_t time = 500000000;
> memcpy(&myArray, &time, 5);
> ```

The behaviour of the program is undefined because you overflow the `uint32_t` object whose size is 4 bytes or less. You attempt to copy 5 bytes.

A correct program:

```
// copy into the array
static_assert(sizeof(std::uint32_t) == 4);
std::memcpy(myArray.data(), &time, 4);

// copy back
std::uint32_t r;
std::memcpy(&r, myArray.data(), 4);
std::chrono::milliseconds dest{r};
```

Just make sure to not copy that array to outside the system, because the data is not portable.

Comment: You are correct, lets assume size 4 here

Comment: @Bodega I added a full example.

Answer (score 0):

Time in `std::chrono::milliseconds` representation of which is not defined aside from ratio type (likely not being a non-static memeber) and period  length in clock ticks It might be represented by anything, e.g. long long or `std::intmax_t` field if that's at least 45 bit long. `std::chrono::milliseconds` is an instantiation of class `std::chrono::duration` and is not a trivially construct-able or copy-able. You don't know layout of those classes, it's not defined and address of `std::chrono::milliseconds` object might not  matching address of data beginning. So pretty much everything you do is an UB.

Only right way to handle this is to form proper arithmetic value in a defined way and to assign it by defined facilities.

Comment: `std::milli` is a ratio and is not related to the contents of `std::chrono::duration`, `std::chrono::milliseconds`'s representation is any 64-bit or larger signed integer. `std::chrono::duration` has a defaulted constructor and copy constructor so is trivially copyable.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Actually, it is any 45 bit or larger signed integer. Although on most systems there are no integers that are between 45 and 64 bits.

Comment: oops, yes you're right, was looking at nanoseconds

Comment: @AlanBirtles in C++11 that would be considered trivail, as I understand C++17 it's not (either default or deleted), but  libc and libstdc++ do not refelect it.  Some commercial compilers do. It doesn't change fact that copied data isn't a milliseconds.

Comment: No mention of that on cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Trivial_copy_constructor